# How to add a transition to the carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, photo-gallery

I have a carousel created on my own and I want to know how I can do that with JS. I know how I can do it by CSS but the problem is the change of the photos. Why change the src so that is my problem. If anyone knows how can I do it in JS it will be alright. Maybe changing the classes or something.

```js
let imagenEnsaladas = document.getElementById("photosEnsaladas");
let buttonNext = document.getElementById("nextPhoto");
let carruselLi = document.getElementById("carruselLista").getElementsByTagName("li");
let positionCarrusel = 0;
let carruselPhotos = [
  "assets/carrusel/ens.-ventresca-300-x300-300x300.png",
  "assets/carrusel/ensalada bacalao200x200.png",
  "assets/carrusel/ensalada-alcachofas-300x-300-300x300.jpg",
  "assets/carrusel/ENsalada-yemas-300x300.png",
  "assets/carrusel/ensalada-de-queso-cabra300x300-300x300.png",
];

window.onload = function playFoto() {
  carruselLi[positionCarrusel].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  if (positionCarrusel >= carruselPhotos.length) {
    positionCarrusel++;
  } else if (positionCarrusel > carruselPhotos.length) {}
  imagenEnsaladas.src = carruselPhotos[positionCarrusel];

  buttonNext.addEventListener("click", clickNextFoto);

  function clickNextFoto() {
    if (positionCarrusel >= carruselPhotos.length - 1) {
      positionCarrusel = 0;
    } else {
      positionCarrusel++;
      console.log(positionCarrusel);
    }
    imagenEnsaladas.src = carruselPhotos[positionCarrusel];
    for (let i = 0; i < carruselLi.length; i++) {
      if (i === positionCarrusel) {
        carruselLi[positionCarrusel].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else {
        carruselLi[i].style.backgroundColor = "#1a1d20";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.textoNovedades {
  margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.tablaNovedadesEnsalada {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  background: #1a1d20;
  color: rgb(246, 225, 185);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
  width: 100%;
}

.carruselEnsaladas {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nextPhoto {
  background-image: url(assets/carrusel/siguiente.jpg);
  background-size: auto;
  background-position-x: 54%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-position-y: 47%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 9vh;
  margin: 7%;
  border: 3px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #999;
}

.tablaNovedadesEnsalada ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="tablaNovedadesEnsalada">

  <div class="carruselEnsaladas">
    <img src="" alt="photos carrusel" id="photosEnsaladas" class="photosEnsaladas">
    <button id="nextPhoto" class="nextPhoto">
            </button>
  </div>

  <p class="textoNovedades">
    <ul id="carruselLista">
      <li value="0"> ensalada de laminas de bacalao</li>
      <li value="1"> Ensalada de alcachofas</li>
      <li value="2"> Ensalada de yemas</li>
      <li value="3">ensalada de ventresca</li>
      <li value="4">Ensalada queso cabra</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</section>
```